# Filtering a List using an object field Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, nested-lists

I have a List, **PointOfServices**, that have an object, **Orders**.

I want to be able to filter the Points of service, based on the **orderType** field within the Orders object.

The outcome I want is to have a list of Points of service that only have Orders with an orderType of 'inventory'.

Is this possible and if so, how would i go about implementing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```dart
    final filtered = pointOfServices.where((pos) => 
        pos.orders.where((order) => order.orderType == 'inventory').isNotEmpty).toList();
```

You are checking if orders list in a single PointOfService contains one order with order type inventory, if such order is present - this serves as a checker  for another filter which takes PointOfService to filtered collection